# Deploying NLP model to AWS for beginners

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nlp, amazon-sagemaker, mlops

I have the task of optimizing search on the website. The search should be for pictures and for text by text query. I have already developed, trained, tested and selected a machine learning model that transforms images and text into a feature vector (Python, based on OpenAI CLIP). This feature vector will be transferred to Elastic Search. Elastic Search will be configured by another specialist.

The model will be used first to determine the feature vector on all existing images and texts, and then be used whenever new content is added or existing content is changed.

There is a lot of existing content (approximately several tens of millions of pictures and texts together). About 100-500 pieces of content are added and changed per day.

I haven't worked much with AWS, but in this case the model needs to be deployed to AWS somehow. Of course, I have the model and the entire project locally, I can write an API app and make a Docker container.

The question is, **what is the best method to deploy this application on AWS**? The best in terms of **speed** and **ease of implementation** (for me as an AWS beginner), as well as **cost optimization**, taking into account the number of requests for the application.

I've seen different possibilities, from simply deploying the application on EC2 (probably the easiest option) to using SageMaker. Also Kubernetes and ECS...

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using SageMaker Hosting endpoint if you need to be able to run vectorization in near-real time any time of the day, or in a SageMaker Training job if you can run vectorization batched, for example once every few hour.

For both systems you can use pre-defined Framework containers and SDK to which you pass a Python code and optionally requirements.txt, or you can create your own image.